# Dual Boot: Can disabled tools be re-enabled after the dual boot is complete?

Tags: linux, installation, unix, multi-boot, operating-systems

I'm a little new to linux. I notice on some dual boot tutorials they'll ask you to disable several things in order to proceed with the dual boot steps. For example if you have windows pre-installed, you can be asked to disable the following:

- Disable Intel Optane memory
- Disable RAID option
- Enable AHCI
- Disable Secure Boot
- Disable Fast Boot
- Disable CSM (Legacy/MBR) boot

So my question is, can you enable all of these things again on your windows boot after the dual boot is complete?

Comment: If an UEFI system, you never want nor need CSM/legacy boot option. You could turn UEFI fast boot on if not reconfiguring system, but know how to get into UEFI as often you have no time to press f keys to get into system. You cannot turn RAID back on, but do not need RAID and have to keep AHCI on to use Linux. Intel Optane - See Intel response that no performance difference between RAID & AHCI.
https://communities.intel.com/thread/121155

Comment: @oldfred Yes, it is a UEFI system.